# Using outbound template for reserved keyword 'yes'

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Is it possible to send an SMS message to contacts which comprises of the Keyword `Yes` using the outbound template in MobileConnect.

I am aware that i can use the Mobile Opt-In template to do the above as `yes` is a reserved keyword and can only be used via the Mobile Opt-In template.

Although, the issue I am facing is the SMS Message I am intending to send which contains `Yes` keyword via the Mobile Opt-In Template exceeds 160 character limit. As there is no concatenation feature in Mobile Opt-In template because of which the message gets dispersed.

Is there a way I can send the SMS message which exceeds 160 characters and contains `yes` keyword using a different solution?